# strange reference to SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, visual-studio-2013

I have an MVC application that I have ported to VS2013 but upon running on my dev machine I have noticed some reference to signalR when I run firebug I don't understand where this come from and why as it seems to be running ever once and then `curl 'http://localhost:62899/4645d6c484b844ff9c09255bb97b07b9/arterySignalR/poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAEumWjTMoPkeDOEXv%2BNHRZwAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAAAh1zpnQcDukz3xmKv6jQ93UejVonzulIb0nfXibU9ozQAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAAC6gz3v487BO50fZx3iXZJKte1SUarM0qPDk9VGtOGWijAAAAD5qwoiK90hXkikTGAOg9nUJzcVRw2x%2BrXg738opqFikHKt4251b6NxJvuH%2F0TKTXhAAAAA51Bi2%2BpR2EmH%2BwbR864v%2Bb0LplFjnpyfFxXvyPrtbB7q7HmbAMmyZbP0HZqGPvxjD%2Fyquhk5vIb4Mjn5VgayGg%3D%3D&messageId=d-45763F85-I%2C0%7CJ%2C4%7CK%2C0&requestUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fmycompany.com%2Fmembership%2Flocation&browserName=Firefox&tid=8&_=1386717058307' -H 'Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -H 'Host: localhost:62899' -H 'Origin: http://mycompany.com' -H 'Referer: http://mycompany.com/this/that' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0'`

does anyone know why/what is happenning.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Browser Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx).

It's [especially useful with Web Essentials](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2013/11/05/making-web-development-wonderful-again-with-web-essentials.aspx).

Comment: Yes this is the new feature in VS 2013. Tried it and like it.